# Proving the union and intersection of an indexed family of sets

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I need to find and prove $\bigcap\limits_{x \in (0,1)}A_{x}$ and $\bigcup\limits_{x \in (0,1)}A_{x}$, for $A_{x} = (-x,x)$ with $x \in (0,1)$. I believe that the intersection is $(0,1)$ and the union is $(-1,1)$. How do I prove this if these are correct?

Comment: If the intersection does not contain $0$, then by definition there has to be an $x\in(0,1)$ such that $0\notin A_x$. Which $x$ is that?

Comment: Why do you think that the intersection includes $1/2$?  Can you explain your thinking?

Comment: ^ Two good questions!!

Comment: I am having trouble following the hints that have kindly been given to me. I do not quite understand what to do with that information.

Comment: If x=3/4 then you have the interval (-3/4,3/4). If x=1/2 then you have the interval (-1/2,1/2). If x=1/4 then you have the interval (-1/4,1/4). If you you keep on choosing a smaller x (as x approaches 0), your intervals are getting smaller and smaller in length.

Comment: The union is fine; the intersection is going to be a single number.

Comment: Is it going to be a single number? x cannot be 0.

Comment: That makes sense. So it seems that the intersection will be the empty set since it cannot include zero. But how do I prove any of this? My professor never really explained how to go about proving anything like this and the book we have is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

We assert that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{x \in(0,1)}A_x=\left \{ 0 \right \}$. Call $E= \displaystyle \bigcap_{x \in(0,1)}A_x$, to simplify the notation. We need to prove that: $\left \{ 0 \right \} \subset E$ and $E \subset \left \{ 0 \right \}$.

To see the first inclusion, note that $-x<0<x$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, which means $0 \in A_x$ for all $x \in (0,1)$, therefore by definition of intersection $0 \in E$.

To see the second inclusion, take $a \in E$, we need to see that $a=0$. We now that there are three, mutually exclusive, possibilities: $a=0$ or $a>0$ or $a<0$ (this is known as the Trichotomy Law)

If $a>0$, take $0<x<1$ such that $x<a$. Therefore $a \not \in (-x,x)$, which means that $a \not \in E$, which contradicts our choice of $a$.

If $a<0$ take $0<x<1$ such that $x<-a$, i.e. $-x>a$, therefore $a \not \in (-x,x)$, which means that $a \not \in E$, which contradicts out choice of $a$.

Since we've exhausted all other possibilites, $a=0$, which completes the proof of the second inclusion. We now conclude $E=\left \{ 0 \right \}$.

You've correctly identified that $F= \displaystyle \bigcup_{x \in (0,1)}A_x=(-1,1)$. Again you need to prove that $F \subset (-1,1)$ and $(-1,1) \subset F$, and to do this take an abritrary element from one set and show that it must be in the other set. I leave the deails to you.